# Are the AWS access keys based on any public standard

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

AWS Access keys for an IAM user or root user consist of two parts: an access key ID and a secret access key. Are the AWS access keys based on any public standard like oAuth ?

Answer (score 0):

No, they are the creation of AWS.

There are some standards within them, such as Access Keys always starting with `AKIA` and temporary keys generated by AWS STS always starting with `ASIA`. See: [Understanding Unique ID Prefixes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_identifiers.html#identifiers-unique-ids)

Comment: Thanks for the link. My question is more around access key ID and a secret access key- are they based on some general standard or AWS invented their own? Fr example EC2 Key pair is based on public key infrastructure (PKI).

Comment: They are AWS-invented.

Comment: It isn't clear to me why the question is being asked, but I would suggest that the answer is not simply that AWS made it up.  The access key ID is an opaque identifier in a form defined by AWS but the secret is a [shared secret](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_secret)
cryptographic key used with a public/standard mechanism called [HMAC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC).  The specific hash used is SHA-256.

Comment: Thanks for the details on HMAC. The reason for my question is  I wanted to know if AWS  Access keys  are similar to github api keys  and if so are they based on some  common open  standard /protocol or methodology and if so this kind of mechanism, is used by other cloud providers like Azure, Google cloud etc. From the answers  above I see there is no common standard.